# How the following set form a basis of given space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A: X \to X$ be a linear operator where $X$ is a hilbert space, and $x \in X$. Defined for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$K_n = \text{span} \{x, Ax, A^2x, \ldots, A^{n-1}x\}$$ Now how to prove that if $A$ is self adjoint and if $x$ cannot be written as sum of $n-1$ eigenvectors of $A$, then the set $$\{x, Ax, A^2x, \ldots, A^{n-1}x\}$$  is a basis of $K_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by eigenvectors you also allow to consider the zero vector. We prove it by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $n = 1$ then $x \neq 0$ (as it cannot be written as a sum of $0$ eigenvectors of $A$) and so $\{ x \}$ is a basis of $K_1 = \operatorname{span} \{ x \}$. Assume the result holds for $n$ and that $x$ cannot be written as a sum of $n$ eigenvectors of $A$. In particular, $x$ cannot be written as a sum of $n - 1$ eigenvectors of $A$ and so the set $\{ x, Ax, \dots, A^{n-1}x \}$ is linearly independent. If $\{ x, \dots, A^n x \}$ is linearly dependent, we have $A^n x \in K_n$ and so $K_n$ is $A$-invariant and, by the induction hypothesis, $n$-dimensional. But then $A|_{K_n}$ is a self-adjoint operator and so can be diagonalized and hence any vector in $K_n$ (in particular $x$) can be written as a sum of at most $n$ eigenvectors of $A$ contradicting our assumption.